# How to debug Node app in IntelliJ with AWS profile

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-cli, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to debug a Node app via the IntelliJ configuration 'debug' button and need to be connected to AWS CLI and have the ability to switch between different 'non-default' profiles/roles to run the app.

Is there anyway to use the AWS Toolkit plugin?  I've downloaded it and it says I'm connected to my profile, however running my Node app it is saying I'm not logged in to AWS.

I've also tried creating a login script and using that as an External Tool to run before the build, and while it lets me log into my default profile, it doesn't pick up the switched profile role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the AWS CLI itself to set or switch AWS profiles in your NodeJS app. Just set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable. Environment variables can be set in the IntelliJ run/debug configuration.